# Get users primary blog URL in MultiSite

Tags: multisite, user-meta

I'm trying to get the primary blog URL of a user. What I have works to grab the details, but if there is more than one blog it just returns them all :(

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );
foreach ($user_blogs AS $user_blog) {
 echo $user_blog->siteurl;
}
```

How can I modify this to output the primary blog URL of the current user?

I'm not sure how to pull it from `wp_usermeta` `primary_blog` table, but that may do the trick.

---

What I would like is the URL from the user primary blog so when they login from the network main site and visit the account area, it shows links to various areas without directing them to the *you attempted to access* message first...

Comment: How do you define “primary” blog for an user? How do you recognize which one is primary?

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/ms-functions.php

/**
27  * Get one of a user's active blogs
28  *
29  * Returns the user's primary blog, if they have one and
30  * it is active. If it's inactive, function returns another
31  * active blog of the user. If none are found, the user
32  * is added as a Subscriber to the Dashboard Blog and that blog
33  * is returned.
34  *
35  * since MU (3.0.0)
36  *
37  * param int $user_id The unique ID of the user
38  * return WP_Site|void The blog object
39  */

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a function for that: `get_active_blog_for_user()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_active_blog_for_user/

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$user_blog = get_active_blog_for_user( $user_id );
echo $user_blog->siteurl;
```

Comment: *BEWARE* that `get_active_blog_for_user()` apparently has side effects: "...If none are found, **the user is added as a Subscriber to the Dashboard Blog** and that blog is returned". So it's not an "information only" function! A safer option would be `get_user_meta( $user_id, 'primary_blog', true )`.